# Vue JS Seperated variable on other file and how to access them

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to make a separate .js file to contain many variables that i can access easily from other component in my Vue project, but I want to know the best way to accomplish this along with some examples.

Comment: Try with sessionstorage

Comment: i want to have a normal variable with some value like basic_url': 'https.....'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add a js file in your project, and import it when you want to use

separate.js

```
export default {
    name: 'jack',
    age: 20
}
```

use it in your vue component

```
import separate from './separate.js'
console.log(separate)
console.log(separate.name)
console.log(separate.age)
```

Comment: but how do i access the name and age?

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp `separate` is an object containing `name` and `age`, you can use it directly

Comment: so all i need to do is call it like seperate.name

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp Right!

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp You'd better set up a public file directory to store the files you need to import, which will be more standard

Comment: if my variable is an array like axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST'
  }. How do i access it? seperate.axiosconfig.header?

Comment: @someone_that_needHelp yes